# Route Reuse Strategy , Route Children's not firing shouldReuseRoute method?

Tags: angular, routes, routereusestrategy

i have declared routes like below

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: NgxMindxRunComponent,
        data: {
            reuse: true
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: NgxMindxRunDiagramComponent,
                data: {
                    reuse: true
                }

            },
            {
                path: 'load/:id',
                component: NgxMindxRunDiagramComponent,
                data: {
                    reuse: true
                }
                
            },
            {
                path: 'file/:fileName',
                component: NgxMindxRunDiagramComponent,
                data: {
                    reuse: true
                },
                
            }],
            
    }
];
```

and the issue is when current route is :
**http://localhost:4200/run/**
then i navigate to **"http://localhost:4200/run/file/1"** every thing is OK!
but when i navigate from  **"http://localhost:4200/run/file/1"** to the **"http://localhost:4200/run/file/2"** the **shouldReuseRoute** method is not firing then cant store component!!
there is same issue for  **"http://localhost:4200/run/load/..."**
it means i'm trying to call store method on RouteReuseStrategy class which i provided in app.module  , but i cant reach
i tried to find same question but i didn't find anything
my other question is , is it OK i used same component with different path , is it make issue in route reuse Strategy usage?

Comment: im using it in the implemented RouteReuseStrategy ,

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem in the past, I've solved this with the following addition in the component:

```js
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
      return false
    }
  }


  ngOnInit(){
     this.route.params.subscribe(...) // your code for handling route
  }
```

Comment: Yes, every route where you can navigate to the same component from the same component.

Comment: thanks , now it is firing shouldReuseRoute but steel its not calling store method in my RouteReuseStrategy class which i provided in app.module , i made some break points and "consol.log" but debugger is not stopping at that lines

Comment: I use the RouteReuseStrategy in the component where the route is being used. In your case I see that you are using the same component for all routes, is that correct? Can you share the code for the store component? And any other relevant code?